# YII2: 'enableAjaxValidation' ,'enableClientValidation' not working for custome rule

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am using YII2 bootstrap/active form.The code is as follow:
In controller:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-terms','enableAjaxValidation' => false,'enableClientValidation' => true,'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false]); ?>
```

....
In Model:

```
  public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['category_name'], 'string'],
        [['category_name'], 'required'],
        [['category_name'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
        [['category_name'], 'checkName', 'message' => 'Category name is already exists.'],
    ];
}   

public function checkName($attribute) {  
        $model = Mycategory::find()->where('category_name = "' . $this->$attribute . '" AND status != "1"'->all();
        if (count($model) > 0) {
            $this->addError($attribute,  'Category name is already exists.');
        }
}
```

The problem is that I am facing an issue is that without ajax the form submitting works fine with correct messages but when I use ajax as above it gives me the error:
`Setting unknown property: yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::skipOnEmpty
and if I remove these skip arguments ajax works fine for required field but in custom rule(checkName function)`it reloads(after reload it shows the error ie ajax not trigerring for custom rule function. Ajax only working for required rule fine). What is the issue?
Edit: Controller code:

```
public function actionCreate() {

  Url::remember();

  $model = new Mycategory;
  $connection = Yii::$app->db;
  $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

     $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());



     $valid = $model->validate();


     if ($valid) {

        try {
           $model->save();
           $transaction->commit();
           Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Category is successfully added.'));
           return $this->redirect('index');
        } catch (Exception $e) {

           $transaction->rollBack();
           Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', Yii::t('app', $e->getMessage()));
           return $this->render('create', [
                       'model' => $model,
           ]);
        }
     } else {

        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', Yii::t('app', 'Please change a few things up and try submitting again. '));
     }
  }

  return $this->render('create', [
              'model' => $model,
  ]);
```

}

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activeform.html  `skipOnEmpty` exists for validation rules not form.

Comment: `skipOnEmpty` is not a property for ActiveForm...

Comment: ok I have moved 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false to model custom rule function like: "[['category_name'], 'checkName', 'message' => 'Category name is already exists.','skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false],"   ...but still not working..

Comment: if I only do ajaxvalidation true not client then ajax works but not printing any error message. without ajax it print error after reload but I want ajax here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`skipOnEmpty` is not a property of `ActiveForm` .. It is a property for Model Rules .. 
May Be rules must be config as

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['category_name'], 'string'],
        [['category_name'], 'required'],
        [['category_name'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
        [['category_name'], 'checkName', 'message' => 'Category name is already exists.' ,'skipOnEmpty' => false],
    ];
}   

public function checkName($attribute) {  
        $model = MyCategory::find()->where('category_name = "' . $this->$attribute . '" AND status != "1"'->all();
        if (count($model) > 0) {
            $this->addError($attribute,  'Category name is already exists.');
        }
}
```

Your Controller Code must be

```
public function actionCreate()
{

    Url::remember();
    $model = new Mycategory;

    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
        return Json::encode(\yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model));
    }

    $connection = Yii::$app->db;
    $transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $valid = $model->validate();

        if ($valid) {
            try {
                $model->save();
                $transaction->commit();
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'Category is successfully added.'));
                return $this->redirect('index');
            } catch (Exception $e) {

                $transaction->rollBack();
                Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', Yii::t('app', $e->getMessage()));
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        } else {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', Yii::t('app', 'Please change a few things up and try submitting again. '));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I have moved 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false to model custom rule function like: "[['category_name'], 'checkName', 'message' => 'Category name is already exists.','skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false]," ...but still not working..

Comment: if I only do ajaxvalidation true not client then ajax works but not printing any error message. without ajax it print error after reload but I want ajax here

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: ok ajax working if I do $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-category','enableAjaxValidation' => true]); but why does the error message not showing?

Comment: after doing ,'enableAjaxValidation' => true flash messages are not displaying.